# transfer evaluation lemma

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, transfer-theory

Let $M$ normal in $H\subseteq G$ with $[G:H]<\infty$ and $H/M$ abelian, and let $T$ be a right transversal for $H$ in $G$, there exists a subset $T_0\subseteq T$ and positive integers $n_t$ for $t\in T_0$ such that 
$$\displaystyle \pi(g)≡\prod_{t\in T_0}tg^{n_t} t^{-1}\mod M$$

It’s from page 119 of M.Isaacs Algebra about transfer theory
I would be so grateful if anybody could help obtain a proof for this.

Comment: Aref, I tried to fix your TeX. Let me know if I made an error.

Comment: Yes, thats is what I wanted to say.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose some $t \in T$. Then $tg=h_1t_1$ for some $t_1 \in T$, $h_1 \in H$. If $t_1 \ne t$, then $t_1g = h_2t_2$ for some $t_2 \in T$, $h_2 \in H$. Keep doing
this until some $t_i$ is repeated, which must happen, because $T$ is finite. In fact the $t_i$ must eventaully cycle, so the first one to repeat must be $t$ itself.

Let $n_t \ge 1$ be minimal such that $t = t_{n_t}$. Then $h_1h_2\cdots h_{n_t} = gt^{n_t}t^{-1}$, so you get one term from the product formula you are trying to prove for $\pi(g)$. We put $t$ into the set $T_0$, but we do not put the other $t_i$ in this cycle, because we have included those already in the product.

If $n_t<n=|G:H|$, then we choose another $t \in T$ that did not arise in the previous cycle and do the same thing, getting another term in the product. Keep going until $\sum n_t = n$.

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for your answer that made me quite clear, but i think there was a typo in second line we should change the place of g and t_1.

Comment: I've corrected the typo!